# Can I get mapping-keys?

Tags: python

If I in python got the string `Hello %(firstname)s`, can I get the expected mapping-keys in that string?

Some example pseudo code:

```
>>> s = 'Hello %(name)s'
>>> s%{'name':'Ulf'}
'Hello Ulf'
>>> # The thing below is roughly what I want.
>>> s.get_map_keys()
['name']
>>> 'Hello %(name)s %(family)s'.get_map_keys()
['name', 'family']
```

NB: I know that this is old-style formatting and that there is better better ways of producing string-templates. But I'm analyzing existing code and do not have control over the strings, I just need to process them and see what replacements are in use.

Comment: If you use new style string formatting - this is quite easy - do you definitely need to support the old style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex to retrieve them:

```
import re

txt = 'Hello %(name)s %(family)s'
re.findall('\%\((.*?)\)', txt)
```

gives:

```
['name', 'family']
```

Comment: The thing to be careful of here is if for some weird reason txt was `'Hello %(name)s %%(family)s'`... - family isn't then a placeholder... (but `%%%(family)s` still would be...)